# Error message in SQL Server: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to calculate the total time duration  in terms of Hours, Minutes, Seconds given some data with logintime and logouttime.

For example the result must be something like "01:44:19". We're using SQL Server 2008

Any idea of how I could do this?

For information, the columns in the table are `int_PK_Id`,'dtm_Date', `dtm_Login_Time`, `dtm_Logout_Time`, `dtm_Duration` etc.

column Name                       datatype
------------                 ---------------------
dtm_Date                       date

dtm_Login_Time                 time(7)

dtm_Logout_Time                time(7)

dtm_Duration                   time(7)

And I wrote this statement:

```
update PS_Time_Sheet  
set dtm_Duration = convert(varchar(5), DateDiff(s,((convert(datetime,[dtm_Date] ) + convert(datetime,dtm_Login_Time))),getdate())/3600)
  +':'+ convert(varchar(5),DateDiff(s,((convert(datetime,[dtm_Date] ) + convert(datetime,dtm_Login_Time))),getdate())%3600/60)
  +':'+convert (varchar(5), DateDiff(s,((convert(datetime,[dtm_Date]) + convert(datetime,dtm_Login_Time))),getdate())%60) 
where int_PK_Id =2
```

Comment: Why are all the `dtm_*` columns not `datetime`s already? What is it with people storing dates/times as non-`datetime`? </rant> Are you sure that every `dtm_*` column contains a valid `datetime`?

Comment: You need to tell us what data type those columns are and some sample data.

Comment: in  dtm_Date  will Store  the current date  means from system date  and like this dtm_Login_Time and dtm_Logout_Time  will  store the current date from he system .

Comment: in dtm_Date will store the current date  from the sysatem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'dtm' means DateTime, you can just minus one from the other, eg

```
select logOutDate - logInDate
```

If your duration column just holds this, I'd suggest either changing it into a computed column on the table, or use a view which performs the above. There is no need to store such a derivative, and can lead to problems as you have to ensure it is correct on changes, etc.

Comment: As the `dtm_` columns don't seem to be `DATETIME` columns (I guess that from the fact that `CONVERT` is necessary to turn them into `DATETIME`), this won't work. I also guess that the problem is that one of the `dtm_` columns does not contain a valid `DATETIME` so `CONVERT` fails.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Indeed, in fact this reads more like a homework question. I can't imagine any professional would store a date as a string, especially where the date is system generated. Think I'll leave this one be!

Comment: *I can't imagine any professional would store a date as a string, especially where the date is system generated.* I agree - shockingly there are **so many** questions here on SO where dates/times are stored as strings or passed by string parameters...

Comment: if  i do  (select logOutDate - logInDate) like   this  then  how i get the format HH:MM:SS  like this